# I can't store a new user on an app depoed on herou

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, laravel-8, database-migration

I created a laravel 8 app in which i can store a new user, locally it works fine but when deployed on heroku at the moment i mike to create a new user this error message appears:
"Trying to access array offset on value of type null"
here is the user class:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;
use Hash;

/**
 * Class User
 *
 * @package App
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $role
 * @property string $remember_token
 * @property string $citizen
*/
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'remember_token', 'role_id', 'citizen_id'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
    
    
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        User::observe(new \App\Observers\UserActionsObserver);
    }
    
    /**
     * Hash password
     * @param $input
     */
    public function setPasswordAttribute($input)
    {
        if ($input)
            $this->attributes['password'] = app('hash')->needsRehash($input) ? Hash::make($input) : $input;
    }
    

    /**
     * Set to null if empty
     * @param $input
     */
    public function setRoleIdAttribute($input)
    {
        $this->attributes['role_id'] = $input ? $input : null;
    }

    /**
     * Set to null if empty
     * @param $input
     */
    public function setCitizenIdAttribute($input)
    {
        $this->attributes['citizen_id'] = $input ? $input : null;
    }
    
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
    }
    
    public function citizen()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Citizen::class, 'citizen_id')->withTrashed();
    }
    
    
    

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
       $this->notify(new ResetPassword($token));
    }
}
```

here is the controller class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\StoreUsersRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\UpdateUsersRequest;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('user_access')) {
            return abort(401);
        }


                $users = User::all();

        return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating new User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('user_create')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        
        $roles = \App\Role::get()->pluck('title', 'id')->prepend(trans('quickadmin.qa_please_select'), '');
        $citizens = \App\Citizen::get()->pluck('num_cin', 'id')->prepend(trans('quickadmin.qa_please_select'), '');

        return view('admin.users.create', compact('roles', 'citizens'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created User in storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\StoreUsersRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreUsersRequest $request)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('user_create')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        $user = User::create($request->all());



        return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing User.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('user_edit')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        
        $roles = \App\Role::get()->pluck('title', 'id')->prepend(trans('quickadmin.qa_please_select'), '');
        $citizens = \App\Citizen::get()->pluck('num_cin', 'id')->prepend(trans('quickadmin.qa_please_select'), '');

        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        return view('admin.users.edit', compact('user', 'roles', 'citizens'));
    }

    /**
     * Update User in storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\UpdateUsersRequest  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(UpdateUsersRequest $request, $id)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('user_edit')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->update($request->all());



        return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
    }


    /**
     * Display User.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('user_view')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        
        $roles = \App\Role::get()->pluck('title', 'id')->prepend(trans('quickadmin.qa_please_select'), '');
        $citizens = \App\Citizen::get()->pluck('num_cin', 'id')->prepend(trans('quickadmin.qa_please_select'), '');$user_actions = \App\UserAction::where('user_id', $id)->get();

        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        return view('admin.users.show', compact('user', 'user_actions'));
    }


    /**
     * Remove User from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('user_delete')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->delete();

        return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
    }

    /**
     * Delete all selected User at once.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function massDestroy(Request $request)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('user_delete')) {
            return abort(401);
        }
        if ($request->input('ids')) {
            $entries = User::whereIn('id', $request->input('ids'))->get();

            foreach ($entries as $entry) {
                $entry->delete();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

finally here is the creation view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h3 class="page-title">المستخدم</h3>
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['admin.users.store']]) !!}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            @lang('quickadmin.qa_create')
        </div>
        
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('name', trans('quickadmin.users.fields.name').'*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('name', old('name'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'required' => '']) !!}
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                    @if($errors->has('name'))
                        <p class="help-block">
                            {{ $errors->first('name') }}
                        </p>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('email', trans('quickadmin.users.fields.email').'*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::email('email', old('email'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'required' => '']) !!}
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                    @if($errors->has('email'))
                        <p class="help-block">
                            {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                        </p>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('password', trans('quickadmin.users.fields.password').'*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'required' => '']) !!}
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                    @if($errors->has('password'))
                        <p class="help-block">
                            {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                        </p>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('role_id', trans('quickadmin.users.fields.role').'*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::select('role_id', $roles, old('role_id'), ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'required' => '']) !!}
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                    @if($errors->has('role_id'))
                        <p class="help-block">
                            {{ $errors->first('role_id') }}
                        </p>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('citizen_id', trans('quickadmin.users.fields.citizen').'', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::select('citizen_id', $citizens, old('citizen_id'), ['class' => 'form-control select2']) !!}
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                    @if($errors->has('citizen_id'))
                        <p class="help-block">
                            {{ $errors->first('citizen_id') }}
                        </p>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    {!! Form::submit(trans('quickadmin.qa_save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

Comment: Please paste the full error message and tell us which line it occurs on. Incomplete / paraphrased messages without a line reference are no use to anyone.

Comment: (1/1) ErrorException
Trying to access array offset on value of type null
in Parser.php line 147at HandleExceptions->handleError()in Parser.php line 147
at Parser->escaped()in Parser.php line 127
at Parser->isFWS()in LocalPart.php line 57
at LocalPart->parse()in EmailParser.php line 48
at EmailParser->parse()in RFCValidation.php line 30at RFCValidation->isValid()in EmailValidator.php line 37
at EmailValidator->isValid()in ValidatesAttributes.php line 633
at Validator->validateEmail()in Validator.php line 398at Validator->validateAttribute()in Validator.php line 277